# restore my child theme backup

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, child-theming

i transferred to a different hosting account and the backup i made belong to the child theme that was madw earlier on the website and now that i need the old settings, so how can i restore my child theme backup on the fresh installed parent theme on WordPress?

and this what appears to me when i restore it to the [parent theme](http://www.l-c-ksa.com/)
And should i use the same settings and widgets and menu that i used during the child theme?

Comment: Try to keep your questions self-contained and focused on code. Links like that expire pretty quickly. This won't help someone else with the same problem if your site is subsequently fixed. Include any relevant code in the body of the question.

Comment: thanks buddy but im a newbie on wordpress and all i have is the backup files should i post the codes or the stylesheet that the theme operate at now?

Comment: There's a lot of things that could have gone wrong here, so this will require some investigation and a lot of back-and-forth, something that Stack Overflow is really not suited for. If you help with a tricky technical problem try [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: Okay thanks a lot man hope it could be solved and godbless